# How do I check if a checkbox is checked on the controller page MVC5

Tags: c#, checkbox, asp.net-mvc-5, checkboxfor

Here is the cshtml page

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("Please tick this box if you are signing up as a Student")
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.isNewlyEnrolled)
</div>
```

I want to check to see if its checked or not in the controller page. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

By adding a boolean parameter named `IsNewlyEnrolled` (case insensitive) to the form's submission endpoint, it will be populated with the state of the checkbox.

```
public HttpResponseMessage MyEndpoint(bool isNewlyEnrolled) {
    // true == checked
    // false == unchecked
}
```

Alternatively, if you're accepting a complex model, add a field/property to that model with the same name.

```
public class MyModel
{
    public bool IsNewlyEnrolled { get; set; }
}

public HttpResponseMessage MyEndpoint(MyModel model) {
    // true == checked
    // false == unchecked
}
```